# How do you set the color of a disabled button using a react-native-paper theme?

Tags: react-native, material-design, react-native-paper

The react-native-paper [docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html) suggest you can set the color of a disabled button using a theme, but this code does not work:

```js
export const buttonTheme = {
  colors: {
    primary: COL_BASE_YELLOW,
    disabled: COL_DARK_HIGHLIGHT,
  },
}

<Button
  loading={submittedPhoneNumber ? true : false}
  mode="contained"
  onPress={() => handleSubmitPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
  theme={buttonTheme}
  disabled={phoneNumber.length < 5 ? true : false}>
  Continue
</Button>
```

The `primary` color works however.
How do I change the color of the button when it is disabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use disabled props, it will always make your button grey, if you want to use your desired colour for disabled mode, do it like this :

```js
<Button
  loading={submittedPhoneNumber ? true : false}
  mode="contained"
  onPress={phoneNumber.length < 5 ? () => {} : () => handleSubmitPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
  color={phoneNumber.length < 5 ? 'darkerColor' : 'fadedColor'}>
  Continue
</Button>
```

Comment: Great solution!! :)

Comment: Hi ! I think that's a great solution, but how can I disable the clicked effect when the button is 'disabled'? thank u

Comment: Your button component must be having prop like isDisabled or similar to it.. check the documentation.

Comment: But the animation gives fake "push" feedback to the user. A prop `disabledStyle` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

From this [Github issue](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1156):

> The text if the contained button depends on the background color of
> the button, which is automatically determined based on of the
> background color is light it dark. Wherever theme is dark or not
> doesn't affect it.
>
> This is the desired behavior. We don't want to show white text on a
> light background because you have a dark theme, otherwise the text
> won't have enough contrast and will be illegible.

Changing the theme to dark **changes** the disabled button color, as I tested. Apart from this, I don't think its possible if you use `react-native-paper`. The author has decided to automatically set the color & background color of the button based on something, but his language is *unclear*.

However, you can give a `labelStyle` prop the button directly, and you could have a conditional in that style.

```
 <Button labelStyle={{ color: phoneNumber.length < 5 ? 'red' : 'green' }}>
```

or,

```
[buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false); // put this outside the render function.
<Button disabled={disabled} labelStyle={{ color: disabled ? 'red' : 'green' }}>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only changes the color of the text in the button.

Comment: Dunno about this before, this is really helpful since I can style the button background color directly through the `style` prop but never knew how to change the color of the text inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm may be late but here's my solution:

```
<Button 
   id="save-phonenumber"
   color="darkColor">
   onClick={doSomething}
   disabled={phoneNumber.length < 5 ? true : false}>
<Button/>
```

In you `Css` file you can add

```
Button#save-phonenumber[disabled] {
  background: "fadedColor"
}
```

Benefit of using this approach is that you don't additionally need to disable the clicking effect when the button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you're caring about light and dark themes at the moment, then you can achieve your goal like this -
I would suggest creating your own Button Component on the top of Paper Button.

```
// extending default Paper Button Component
<PaperButton style={[ props.disabled && { backgroundColor: 'cccccc' } ]}>
  {children}
</PaperButton>


// Using component...
<MyButton disabled={disabled}>
  Click Me!
</MyButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by passing the `backgroundColor` property to the style prop.

```
<Button
  mode="contained"
  color={colors.backgroundYellow}
  style={{ backgroundColor: colors.backgroundYellow }}
  loading={isLoading}
  disabled={isLoading}>
    Button
</Button>
```